# foreach of arrays extracted from XML documents, I'm getting repeated results too. How to fix this?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I got this XML file:
(items.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<items>
...
    <item id="1546" article="a" name="item 1546 name">
        <attribute key="weight" value="12000" />
        <attribute key="slotType" value="two-handed" />
        <attribute key="itemType" value="distance" />
        <attribute key="range" value="5" />
        <attribute key="hitChance" value="1" />
        <attribute key="attack" value="3" />
    </item>
...
    <item id="4355" article="an" name="item 4355 name">
        <attribute key="weight" value="19000" />
        <attribute key="itemType" value="distance" />
        <attribute key="range" value="5" />
        <attribute key="hitChance" value="4" />
        <attribute key="attack" value="9" />
    </item>
...
</items>
```

And a php page that gets an array saved in a mysql table with this format:

> "..." => "...", "..." => "...", "1546" => "27", "4355" => "1"
>
> > Obs: this is the format: "item id" => "amount"

I'm trying to list the item attributes from (items.xml) with the item_ids inside the array.
Here is the page's php code:

```
$c_item_reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$c_item_reader->open($config['site']['server_path'].'data/items/items.xml')) {
    die("Failed to open 'items.xml'");
}
$item_fromdb = $db['items_array']; // that's the array I was talking about earlier...
$f_item = array();
$f_bits = explode(",",$item_fromdb);
foreach ($f_bits as $b) {
    $b = str_replace('"', '', $b);
    $bobs = explode(" => ", $b);
    $f_item[$bobs[0]] = $bobs[1];
}
while($c_item_reader->read()) {
    if ($c_item_reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $c_item_reader->name == 'item') {
        $id = $c_item_reader->getAttribute('id');
        $name = $c_item_reader->getAttribute('name');
        $item = $c_item_reader->expand();
        $attributes = array();
        foreach($item->childNodes as $attribute) {
            if(get_class($attribute) != 'DOMElement') continue;
            $attributes[] = (string) '"'.$attribute->getAttribute('key').'" => "'.$attribute->getAttribute('value').'"';
        }
        $ff_dsds = implode(",",$attributes);
        foreach($f_item as $f_itemid => $f_itemamount){
            if($id == $f_itemid){
                $f_item_attr = array();
                $f_bits_attr = explode(",",$ff_dsds);
                foreach ($f_bits_attr as $b2) {
                    $b2 = str_replace('"', '', $b2);
                    $bobs2 = explode(" => ", $b2);
                    $f_item_attr[$bobs2[0]] = $bobs2[1];
                }
                foreach($f_item_attr as $f_attr_name => $f_attr_value){
                    if($l_attr_id == "weight")
                        $y_weight = $f_attr_value;
                    if($l_attr_id == "slotType")
                        $y_slottype = $f_attr_value;
                    if($l_attr_id == "itemType")
                        $y_itemtype = $f_attr_value;
                    if($l_attr_id == "range")
                        $y_range = $f_attr_value;
                }
                if($y_weight)
                    $f_weight = 'It weighs '.number_format($y_weight / 100, 2, '.', '').' oz each.';
                if($y_itemtype){
                    if($y_slottype == "two-handed"){
                        $description = 'Two handed weapon...';
                    }else{
                        $description = 'no restriction...';
                    }
                }else{
                    $description = '<no item type>';
                }
                echo '<img src="images/items/'.$id.'.gif"></br>0-'.$f_itemamount.' '.$name.''.($f_itemamount > 1 ? 's' : '').'</br>'.$f_weight.'</br>'.$description.'</br></br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In part, this codes are working to print on `echo` the content I need...
But the printed result was supposed to be:

> ...
>
> ...
>
> 0-27 item 1546 names
>  It
>   weighs 120.00 oz each.
>  Two handed weapon...
>
> 0-1 item 4355 name
>  It weighs
>   190.00 oz each.
>  no restriction...

and this is coming instead:

> ...
>
> ...
>
> 0-27 item 1546 names
>  It
>   weighs 120.00 oz each.
>  Two handed weapon...
>
> 0-1 item 4355 name
>  It weighs
>   190.00 oz each.
>  Two handed weapon...

**Note** that the other attributes are just fine, only the description are repeating... Maybe because in the xml file some items has the slotType attribute and others not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `$y_slottype` variable (among others). In your current implementation, this variable is assigned when you encounter an `<attribute>` tag with the key `slotType`. However, it **is never reset** in the case that no respective `<attribute>` tag is found.

In other words: when an item does not have an `<attribute>` tag with `key="slotType"`, the `$y_slottype` variable will still have its value from the previous iteration. One solution would be to reset the variable at the beginning of each iteration:

```
foreach($f_item as $f_itemid => $f_itemamount){
    $y_weight = NULL;
    $y_itemtype = NULL;
    $y_range = NULL;
    $y_slottype = NULL;
    // ...
    foreach($f_item_attr as $f_attr_name => $f_attr_value){
        if($l_attr_id == "weight")
            $y_weight = $f_attr_value;
        if($l_attr_id == "slotType")
            $y_slottype = $f_attr_value;
        if($l_attr_id == "itemType")
            $y_itemtype = $f_attr_value;
        if($l_attr_id == "range")
            $y_range = $f_attr_value;
    }
```

Comment: first try and it worked... wow I thought when an item does not have an attribute with the desired key the return would be 0 and not previous one... thank you so much!

Comment: @user3050478: Read the explanation in the answer again. It has no return value at all, it's your very own variable that you've forgotten to initialize before the loop was entered as a precondition and also reset as a postcondition (depending on how strict you write your code).

Comment: ya I had to change those NULL for '' and the items.xml cant be edited so i cant add the slotType key to the other tags without it

Answer (score 1):

Easy, you have to set initial values for those variables, take a look:

```
foreach($f_item as $f_itemid => $f_itemamount){

            $y_weight = '';
            $y_slottype = '';
            $y_itemtype = '';
            $y_range = '';

            if($id == $m_loot_id){
                $f_item_attr = array();
                $f_bits_attr = explode(",",$ff_dsds);
                foreach ($f_bits_attr as $b2) {
                    $b2 = str_replace('"', '', $b2);
                    $bobs2 = explode(" => ", $b2);
                    $f_item_attr[$bobs2[0]] = $bobs2[1];
                }
                foreach($f_item_attr as $f_attr_name => $f_attr_value){
                    if($l_attr_id == "weight")
                        $y_weight = $f_attr_value;
                    if($l_attr_id == "slotType")
                        $y_slottype = $f_attr_value;
                    if($l_attr_id == "itemType")
                        $y_itemtype = $f_attr_value;
                    if($l_attr_id == "range")
                        $y_range = $f_attr_value;
                }
...
```